# how to map classes in hibernate using the class attribute?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a problem in my maven project
click the links below to see it
I added this to my hibernate.cfg but didn't work

```
<mapping package="com.redpass.entities"/>
<mapping class="com.redpass.entities.MyReference"/>
```

[console error](https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/11377223_10204615368845604_4680174219591365167_n.jpg?oh=775a20fa5a2d5267596cb536dafbe02a&oe=560C9C00)

[Project Explorer](https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/11329811_10204615368765602_1196650476134833729_n.jpg?oh=8b50ae706e6775e3306af117e6a28183&oe=55EBCDC7)

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avocatbd</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- <mapping package="com.redpass.entities"/>
        <mapping class="com.redpass.entities.MyReference"/> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Could you add more details specailly your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: I added the .cfg file and click console error and Project Explorer above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should add this:

```
configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        return configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .build());
```

to my HibernateUtil Class to tell that we want to configure using the hibernate.cfg.xml file and map the classes like this:

```
<mapping class="com.redpass.entities.Partie"/>
<mapping class="com.redpass.entities.Societe"/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question, do not post this as answer.